# Cannot set padding to 0 on Material UI Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a normal `Button` from `Material-UI` for `React` tried adding the following style

```
button: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    padding:0
  }
```

to this button

```
<Button className={classes.button}> I'm a Test Button </Button>
```

What I obtain is that the padding for the **right/left** side is correctly set to 0, while the one for **top/bottom** is not updated, see the attached image.

Is this a bug? Or what's the correct way to achieve this?

*EDIT:*
Material-UI version: ***v1.0.0-beta.20***

[image]

Comment: Hi! What material-ui version you are using? Also, from the top of my mind, try changing line-height or height properties. Thanks!

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins the latest, v1.0.0-beta.20

Comment: Ok, I just added my previous comment with some hints. Let me know if they work =)

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins tried `lineHeight:0, height:0, maxHeight:0,`, still no luck. I also found that if I use a shorter Title I also got the `left/right` padding not applied, it looks like there is a minimum `height/width`, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, there is. And as for what I could see testing here, this is caused by the `min-height` property of the root key of the Button element. Try setting `minHeight: 0`. See if that works! Try with `minWidth`too if necessary

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins yes it works, if you mind posting an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the min-height and min-width properties of the root key of the Button element. Setting `minHeight: 0` and/or `minWidth:0` should fix it:

```
button: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    padding:0,
    minHeight: 0,
    minWidth: 0,
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

This answer is more accurate than @Brunno

```
<Button sx={{ minHeight: 0, minWidth: 0, padding: 0 }}>My Button</Button>
```